# How to make a string and an integer as paramaters in binary search tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm new to the programming world and I have been stuck in the same problem for couple days. My assignment is to create a binary search tree that takes a string and an integer as parameters and stores the pair in the tree. My code works fine for the string but not for integers, for example if I input "John" for the string and "2" for the integers, it will only output "John"! My whole code is below to give you guys an idea of what's going on.

BST.cpp:

```
#include"BST.h"
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

BST::BST()
{
    this->root = NULL;      //root is NULL in the start
}

BST::~BST()
{
    clear(root);            //delete all nodes
}

void BST::clear(Node* current)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return;

    clear(current->getLeft());          //clear left subtree
    clear(current->getRight());         //clear right subtree
    delete current;                     //delete this node
}

void BST::Insert(string num, int data)
{
    //create new node to be inserted
    Node *n = new Node();
    n->setData(num, data);
    n->setLeft(NULL);
    n->setRight(NULL);


    if(this->root == NULL)      //if root is null, simply add at root
        root = n;

    else
        InsertHelper(root,n);   //call helper to insert
}

void BST::InsertHelper(Node* current, Node* newnode)
{
    if(current == NULL)     
        return;

    //node should be inserted at right subtree
    if(current->getData() <= newnode->getData()){

        //if no node at right
        if(current->getRight() == NULL )    
            current->setRight(newnode);     //add at right node

        else
            InsertHelper(current->getRight(), newnode);     //insert in right subtree
    }
    else{

        if(current->getLeft() == NULL){         //if no node at left
            current->setLeft(newnode);          //add at left
        }else{
            InsertHelper(current->getLeft(), newnode);      //insert in left subtree
        }
    }
}


bool BST::find(string num)
{
    return findHelper(root,num);
}

bool BST::findHelper(Node *current,string num)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return false;

    if(current->getData() == num)       //if number is founf
        return true;                    

    if(num < current->getData())        //if number is less than current node
        return findHelper(current->getLeft(),num);      //go to left tree
    else
        return findHelper(current->getRight(),num);     //go to right tree
}


void BST::min()
{
    findMinHelper(root);
}

void BST::findMinHelper(Node* current)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return;

    if(current->getLeft() == NULL)          //if no node at right
        cout<<current->getData();           //current has min data
    else
        findMinHelper(current->getLeft());  //check on left subtree
}

void BST::max()
{
    findMaxHelper(root);
}

void BST::findMaxHelper(Node * current)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return;

    if(current->getRight() == NULL)             //if no node at right
        cout<<current->getData();               //current node has max data
    else
        findMaxHelper(current->getRight());     //check on right subtree
}

void BST::LoadFromFile(string filename)
{
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open(filename.c_str());         //open input file

    if(fin.fail())
        cout<<"Unable to open input file";
    else{

        string x;
        fin>>x;
        while(!fin.eof())       //while file is not ended
        {
            //  Insert(x);          //insert in tree
            fin >>x;            //read next numbers
        }
        cout<<"Data successfully loaded!!"<<endl;
    }
}

void BST::save_file(string filename)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(filename.c_str());        //open output file
    saveHelper(fout,root);              //call helper function
    cout<<"Successfully saved\n\n";
}

void BST::saveHelper(ofstream &fout, Node* current)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return;

    saveHelper(fout,current->getLeft());        //save left tree
    fout<<current->getData() << " ";            //save current data
    saveHelper(fout,current->getRight());       //save right tree
}

void BST::Print()
{
    printHelper(root);
}

void BST::printHelper(Node *current)
{
    if(current == NULL)     //stop if NULL
        return;

    printHelper(current->getLeft());        //print left tree
    cout<<current->getData() << " ";        //print current node data
    printHelper(current->getRight());       //print right tree
}

void BST::Delete(string num){
    root = DeleteHelper(root,num);
}

Node* BST::DeleteHelper(Node *current, string num)
{
    if(current == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Node *tobeReturned;

    if (current->getData() == num) {          //if key is found

        if (current->getLeft() == NULL) {        //no node at left

            tobeReturned = current->getRight();
            delete current;
            return tobeReturned;          //right subtree should replace this node

        } else if (current->getRight() == NULL) {

            tobeReturned = current->getLeft();
            delete current;
            return tobeReturned;
        } else {

            //find maximum node in the left subtree
            Node * maxnode = findMaximum(current->getLeft());

            //copy values from max node to this node
            //      current->setData(maxnode->getData());

            //delete the max node 
            current->setLeft(DeleteHelper(current->getLeft(), num));
        }
        cout<<"Deleted!!!";
    } else {        //not found
        if (num < current->getData()) {
            current->setLeft(DeleteHelper(current->getLeft(),num));
        } else {
            current->setRight(DeleteHelper(current->getRight(), num));
        }
    }
    return current;
}

Node* BST::findMaximum(Node * n)
{
    if(n->getRight() == NULL)       //if no node at right, current is maximum
        return n;
    return findMaximum(n->getRight());      //find in right subtree
}
```

BST.h:

```
#ifndef BST_H_
#define BST_H_

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>

#include "Node.h"

//BST class
class BST{

    private:
        Node * root;        //root node pointer

    public:
        BST();                                  //constructor
        ~BST();                                 //destructor
        void Insert(string num, int data);                  //Inserts new number in tree
        bool find(string num);                      //finds whether a number is present in tree
        void min();                             //find and print minimum number in the tree
        void max();                             //find and print maximum number in the tree
        void save_file(string filename);        //save the tree to file
        void Delete(string num);                    //deletes a number from tree
        void LoadFromFile(string filename);     //loads numbers from file to tree
        void Print();                           //print tree to stdout


        //private functions used as helper functions in the public operations
    private:
        void printHelper(Node *root);
        bool findHelper(Node *root,string num);
        void InsertHelper(Node* current, Node* newnode);
        void findMinHelper(Node* current);
        void findMaxHelper(Node * current);
        void saveHelper(ofstream &fout, Node* current);
        Node* DeleteHelper(Node *current, string num);
        Node * findMaximum(Node * n);
        void clear(Node *currnt);
};

#endif
```

driver.cpp:

```
#include"BST.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_menu()
{
    cout<<"\n\nEnter 1 to Insert new number."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 2 to Find number."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 3 to Print."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 4 to print min."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 5 to print max."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 6 to save to file."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 7 to delete a number."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 8 to load data from file."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 9 to exit."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
}

int main()
{
    bool done = false;
    int choice,data;
    string fname, num;
    BST tree;

    while(!done)
    {
        print_menu();
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Enter key: ";
                cin >> num;
                cout<<"Enter data:";
                cin >> data;
                tree.Insert(num,data);
                cout<<"Number add successfully"<<endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Enter number: ";
                cin >> num;
                if(tree.find(num))
                    cout<<"Number exists!!"<<endl;
                else
                    cout<<"Number not found"<<endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                tree.Print();
                break;
            case 4:
                tree.min();
                break;
            case 5:
                tree.max();
                break;
            case 6:
                cout<<"Enter filename:";
                cin>>fname;
                tree.save_file(fname);
                break;
            case 7:
                cout<<"Enter number:";
                cin>>num;
                tree.Delete(num);
                break;
            case 8:
                cout<<"Enter filename:";
                cin>>fname;
                tree.LoadFromFile(fname);
                break;
            case 9:
                done = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid option selected..\n";
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Node.cpp:

```
#include"Node.h"
#include<string>

Node::Node()
{
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}


void Node::setData(string num, int data)
{
    this->num = num;
}


string Node::getData()
{
    return this->num;
}

void Node::setLeft(Node *l)
{
    this->left = l;
}

Node* Node::getLeft()
{
    return this->left;
}

void Node::setRight(Node *r)
{
    this->right = r;
}

Node* Node::getRight()
{
    return this->right;
}
```

Node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class Node{

    private:
        int data;                       //number
        Node *left;                     //left child
        Node *right;                    //right child
        std::string num;
    public:
        Node();                         //constructor
        void setData(string num, int data);         //sets number in node
        string getData();                   //return numbers from node
        void setLeft(Node *l);          //sets left child pointer
        Node* getLeft();                //returns left child pointer
        void setRight(Node *r);         //sets right child pointer
        Node* getRight();               //return right child pointer
};


#endif
```

Does anyone see the problem on my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `node.cpp`, you are not setting the integer value

```
void Node::setData(string num, int data)
{
    this->num = num;
    this->data = data; //missing line!
}
```

Also while printing, you need to modify a bit

```
cout<<current->getName() << " " << current->getNumber() << " " ;
```

Add these methods to your `Node` class : `getName` & `getNumber` which return string and integer of the class respectively. Use them instead of `getData` method

Comment: After making the suggestion changes, everything is working fine. Thanks a lot